# jQuery XML Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, soap

i have some issue to navigate on my XML File. Here is the structure of my File :

```
<m_params enc:itemType="enc:Struct" enc:arraySize="4" xsi:type="enc:Array">
    <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
        <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">image</m_name>
        <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">9f00de47f9f07ec0c7389875e4739c2b.png</m_value>
        <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">3</m_numType>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
        <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">weblink</m_name>
        <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">http://www.xxx.com</m_value>
        <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">2</m_numType>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
        <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">redirect-type</m_name>
        <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">2</m_value>
        <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>
    </item>
    <item xsi:type="enc:Struct">
        <m_name xsi:type="xsd:string">is-logo</m_name>
        <m_value xsi:type="xsd:string">1</m_value>
        <m_numType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</m_numType>
    </item>
```

So basically i need to get the "enc:arraySize" attribute, then make a loop with the value of it (here 4 times).

And then get all the node value of the item (m_name, m_value, m_numType)

So actually i'm doing this to get the arraySize (it work)

```
var node = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("m_params")[0].getAttribute("enc:arraySize");
```

But them when i'm trying to get the node value of m_name for example, it didn't work and i don't understand :

```
var node = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("m_value")[0];
    alert(node.nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it might not look logical at first, but the text is stored in a text node, which is a child of your m_value node. Try this:

```
var node = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("m_value")[0];
var textnode = node.childNodes[0];
alert(textnode.nodeValue);
```

As for the loop, try this (untested, unoptimised):

```
var items = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
   var item = items[i];

   var name = item.getElementsByTagName("m_name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var value = item.getElementsByTagName("m_value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
   var numType = item.getElementsByTagName("m_numType")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

   // Do whatever you want with your values
}
```

For more info on XML DOM parsing see http://w3schools.com/dom/default.asp